Does this token contract look right?
I am not a coder or even thought about code until my run in with one of these guys (smart contract) and ill be honest its been rather interesting trying to work this out and learning a lot i think would be very interesting.  But for now some help would be absolutely appreciated...
I now spent 3 days now trying to read this smart contract that a money recover company had setup to apparently return money that taken when a broker took off with through a Ponzi pyramid scam.
To me it just does not look right, with words or code like  return, not payable its not validated or have a source code.
Below is as far as i have been to get it with it, a little readable to some one with no coding experience.. Help would be great and highly appreciated as i feel this my be a scam to get what crypto i have left, code below..
thanks,
def storage:
  symbol is array of uint256 at storage 0
  name is array of uint256 at storage 1
  decimals is uint8 at storage 2
  _totalSupply is uint256 at storage 3
  balanceOf is mapping of uint256 at storage 4
  allowance is mapping of uint256 at storage 5

def name(): # not payable
  return name[0 len name.length]

def decimals(): # not payable
  return decimals

def _totalSupply(): # not payable
  return _totalSupply

def balanceOf(address _owner): # not payable
  return balanceOf[addr(_owner)]

def symbol(): # not payable
  return symbol[0 len symbol.length]

def allowance(address _owner, address _spender): # not payable
  return allowance[addr(_owner)][addr(_spender)]


Regular functions

def _fallback() payable: # default function
  revert

def totalSupply(): # not payable
  return (_totalSupply - balanceOf[0])

def safeSub(uint256 _a, uint256 _b): # not payable
  require _b <= _a
  return (_a - _b)

def safeAdd(uint256 _a, uint256 _b): # not payable
  require _a + _b >= _a
  return (_a + _b)

def safeDiv(uint256 _a, uint256 _b): # not payable
  require _b > 0
  require _b
  return (_a / _b)

def safeMul(uint256 _a, uint256 _b): # not payable
  if _a:
      require _a
      require _a * _b / _a == _b
  return (_a * _b)

def approve(address _spender, uint256 _value): # not payable
  allowance[caller][addr(_spender)] = _value
  log Approval(
        address tokenOwner=_value,
        address spender=caller,
        uint256 tokens=_spender)
  return 1

def transfer(address _to, uint256 _value): # not payable
  require _value <= balanceOf[caller]
  balanceOf[caller] -= _value
  require balanceOf[addr(_to)] + _value >= balanceOf[addr(_to)]
  balanceOf[addr(_to)] += _value
  log Transfer(
        address from=_value,
        address to=caller,
        uint256 tokens=_to)
  return 1

def approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _amount, bytes _extraData): # not payable
  allowance[caller][addr(_spender)] = _amount
  log Approval(
        address tokenOwner=_amount,
        address spender=caller,
        uint256 tokens=_spender)
  require ext_code.size(_spender)
  call _spender.receiveApproval(address spender, uint256 value, address token, bytes extraData) with:
       gas gas_remaining wei
      args caller, _amount, addr(this.address), Array(len=_extraData.length, data=_extraData[all])
  if not ext_call.success:
      revert with ext_call.return_data[0 len return_data.size]
  return 1

def transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value): # not payable
  require _value <= balanceOf[addr(_from)]
  balanceOf[addr(_from)] -= _value
  require _value <= allowance[addr(_from)][caller]
  allowance[addr(_from)][caller] -= _value
  require balanceOf[addr(_to)] + _value >= balanceOf[addr(_to)]
  balanceOf[addr(_to)] += _value
  log Transfer(
        address from=_value,
        address to=_from,
        uint256 tokens=_to)
  return 1


It does look like a regular token contract. Unfortunately it looks like a reverse engineered so it is not the real contract just a pseudocode.

It's not pseudocode, it's Vyper. For more information about Vyper can be found at https://docs.vyperlang.org/

@MikkoOhtamaa It looks like vyper/python but it isn't 100% vyper. It looks like the Etherscan decompiled bytecode produced by Panoramix decompiler.

Thank you ismael. You are are right, it is not 1:1. Panoramix might have its language inspired from early Vyper.
